# Handling actionPerformed on JComboBox only when user confirmed selection

Tags: java, swing, search, keyboard, jcombobox

When I register ActionListener on a non-editable JComboBox it fires actionPerformed() every time user changes selected item with arrows keys or with context search (typing the first letter of the item name).

I found similar question here: 
[How to make JComboBox selected item not changed when scrolling through its popuplist using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194786/how-to-make-jcombobox-selected-item-not-changed-when-scrolling-through-its-popup).  But that solution doesn't cover context search option. It fires actionPerformed() when I type something.

How to determine when user confirms selected item using enter key or mouse click?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

better would be implements [ItemListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) (fired twice SELECTED and DESELECTED), than [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [KeyBindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), maybe with succes this simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984621/java-swing-jcombobox-drop-down-list-change-listener-before-clicking/7984692#7984692)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

public class PopupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JComboBox c = new JComboBox();
        c.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getSource());
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getSource());
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getSource());
            }
        });
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(c);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private PopupTest() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I need is the opposite.
I need to get event only when user confirms selection by mouse click or by enter key pressing. (Moment when combobox popup hides).
I tried to examine is popup visible right in the actionPerformed()
but it seems to be that action fires before popup hides.

Comment: `ItemListener` & `JComboBox#isPopupVisible()`

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for answer. This is what I really needed.
I also added actionListener for the case when user moves through the combobox with arrows keys when popup is invisible:

```
scriptsCombobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox source = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        if(!source.isPopupVisible()){
            //update data
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad you could resolve your problem.  If @mKorbel's answer solved your problem, please accept it, or accept yours, so that others can learn from your solution.  Cheers~