# JComboBox selection finalization event

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to act if a JComboBox selection changes **through clicking on an item, or pressing ENTER preceded by keyboard navigation**?

As for simply listening to the selection change, one can choose to use ItemListener or ActionListener, but the event will be fired when the list selection changes **regardless of whether it's still displayed to the user**. For example, when the user changes selection using arrow keys, the event will be fired on the item the user wished to select AND all the items that must have been selected in order to get to that item.

Comment: You may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/163188); given X, it may help if you explain Y.

Comment: I actually found the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5194855/1003592 But thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ActionListener to check for Action Command "comboBoxChanged".